# Translating HTTP POST body to c# request

Tags: c#, html, http, post

I have intercepted the POST request I need to simulate as

> _method=POST&data%5BListing%5D%5Blisting_category_id%5D=2&data%5BListing%5D%5Blisting_subcategory_id%5D=211

How do I send this in C# using HTTPClient? I found the following sample but this passes a dictionary. What do I need to construct to simulate the above request as it isn't clear to me

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:6740");
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("", "login")
            });
            var result = await client.PostAsync("/api/Membership/exists", content);
            string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
        }
```

Comment: I assume your purpose is get the result, so I suggest you use the `HttpWebRequest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `HttpWebRequest` is easier in your case.

```
string Url = "http://localhost:6740";
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest;
string result = null;

//POST method here.
request.Method = "post";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

//Parameters here.
string param = "para1=data1&para2=data2";

//Maybe you need unicode or other encoding...
byte[] bs = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(param);

using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    reqStream.Write(bs, 0, bs.Length);
}

using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
}
```

PS. This sample code is copied from a Chinese website.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I translate the POST string above to params? Am I right in thinking it is "[Listing][listing_category_id]" as param 1 key, with value of 2, and "[Listing][listing_subcategory_id]" as param 2 key, with value of 211?

Comment: @NZJames That's right. And there's a good website https://urldecode.org can decode these for you